# Node<> and toString() methods when finding elements and creating new lists

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, nodes, element

Not sure how to fill in the last two methods at the bottom of this code. The findNode(E e) should return the Node that contains the element e, or it returns null if the list is empty. The last toString() method is meant to override a previous one in another class and prints the content of a list.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> {

    public static class Node<E> {
        private E element; // reference to the element stored at

        private Node<E> prev; // reference to the previous node in the

        private Node<E> next; // reference to the subsequent node in

        public Node(E element, Node<E> prev, Node<E> next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }
        // public accessor methods

        public E getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public Node<E> getPrev() {
            return prev;
        }

        public Node<E> getNext() {
            return next;
        }
        // Update methods

        public void setPrev(Node<E> p) {
            prev = p;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
            next = n;
        }
    } //----------- end of nested Node class -----------

    // instance variables of the DoublyLinkedList
    private Node<E> header; // header sentinel
    private Node<E> trailer; // trailer sentinel
    private int size = 0; // number of elements in the list

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        header = new Node<>(null, null, null); // create header
        trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null); // trailer is preceded by

        header.setNext(trailer); // header is followed by

    }
    // public accessor methods

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public void addLast(E e) {
        addBetween(e, trailer.getPrev(), trailer); // place just before the

    }
    // public update methods

    public void addBetween(E e, Node<E> predecessor, Node<E> successor) {
        // create and link a new node
        Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, predecessor, successor);
        predecessor.setNext(newest);
        successor.setPrev(newest);
        size++;

    }

    public Node<E> findNode(E e) {
        E element = e;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        int node = 0;
        Node<E> temp = header;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.getNext() == element) {
                return node;
            }
            node++;
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        ArrayList<E> ref = new ArrayList<>();
        int counter = 1;

        return ref.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about `temp.getNext() == element` What type does `getNext` return? Is it the same type as `element`? What is the difference between using `==` and `.equals`? Which should you use here?

Comment: And what's the reason for `int node = 0;` and `return node;`? That last line gives you a compile error, doesn't it?

Comment: Your `toString` method overrides the implementation of `toString` in the `Object` class (because that's the class that `DoublyLinkedList` extends). You'll need to explain in more detail what you want it to do.

Comment: ```findNode``` does a linear search.  I would recommend use a for loop.  This method should contain no more than 4 lines of code.  The method ```toString()``` probably returns a string similar to ```ArrayList```.  You will wan to use a ```StringBuilder```.  Append the first element to the buffer, then append , follows by the next element.  You can use a for loop for this.  When the loop terminates, return the string of the string builder object.  This should not be more than 10 lines.